# How to compare Referer URL in Django Request to another URL using reverse()?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

How can I compare the referer URL and `reverse()` url?

Here is my current code:

```
if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == reverse('dashboard'):
    print 'Yeah!'
```

But this doesn't work because the reverse will output **`/dashboard`** while `HTTP_REFERER` output `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/`

My current solution is:

```
if reverse('dashboard') in request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'):
    print 'Yeah!'
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `urlparse` to get the path element from a URL. In Python3:

```
from urllib import parse
path = parse.urlparse('http://localhost:8000/dashboard/').path
```

and in Python 2:

```
import urlparse
path = urlparse.urlparse('http://localhost:8000/dashboard/').path
```